# Why is uniqueness of basis representation necessary in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say that we have an ordered basis $\mathcal{B} = (e_1, \dots,e_n)$ of some vector space $V$. Let $\varphi : V \to \mathbb{F}^{n\times 1}$ be the function which assigns every vector its unique basis representation, $\varphi : v \mapsto [v]_{\mathcal{B}}$. $\mathcal{B}$ ensures that every vector is uniquely representable, which implies that $\varphi$ is a function. But I don't see why this is necessary to develop Linear Algebra. If we don't require $\mathcal{B}$ to be a basis (though it must still span $V$), we only get extra representations of vectors, which does not seem problematic. Viewing $\varphi$ as a set (relation), it seems that only $\varphi^{-1}$ being a function is crucial. If we don't have this, we don't know how to translate representations back to vectors. But it seems that we have this even without $\mathcal{B}$ being a basis.

**Claim.** If $\varphi(u) = \varphi(v)$, then $u = v$.

**Proof.** Because $\varphi(u) = \varphi(v)$, $u$ and $v$ can be written as linear combinations of $e_i \in \mathcal{B}$ ($\mathcal{B}$ is not necessarily a basis!) identically, which means that $u = v$.

My question now is, given the above, why do we even need the uniqueness of representation which $\mathcal{B}$ being a basis affords us? Thanks!

Comment: Why do we need a basis in the first place? Once we have it, it has this nice property. It is used in almost every statement in linear algebra. You could ask as well "Why is uniqueness of prime decomposition of integers necessary in number theory"? This is a broad question with potentially very long answers (almost all of linear algebra arising).

Comment: If your potential basis turns out to have such redundancies, it is called a spanning set, or more generally a generating set, rather than a basis (note that a basis is also a spanning set, just like squares are also rectangles). These are also important, and basically the only substitute in cases when a basis doesn't exist (not only vector spaces, but also modules, algebras, and many other algebraic structures).

Comment: I don't see how this is "opinion-based" - the OP is asking why a particular aspect of a definition is important, and that definitely has an objective answer.

Comment: With a basis, you know that if a vector has a nonzero representation in that basis, then it's not zero.  Without a basis, you can't tell if it's zero or not from the representation.  This means you can't even answer questions like when two vectors are equal. Is is $(1,1,0) = (0,0,1)$? If this is a representation in the  "basis" given by $e_1 = (1,0), e_2 = (0,1), e_3 = (1,1)$ then the answer is yes.  In some other basis, the answer is probably no. It's hard to do any computations when you can't define equality.

Comment: Incidentally: Questioning the motivation behind basic definitions is an important step in learning anything. Vastly preferred over "help me do this homework problem"-type questions. So I give +1.

Answer (score 3):

Think about how we actually use bases - for example, for defining linear functions between vector spaces $V$ and $W$. If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $V$, then we get an **exact** correspondence between linear maps from $V$ to $W$ and arbitrary (set) functions from $\mathcal{B}$ to $W$. If $\mathcal{B}$ were too big, some functions from $\mathcal{B}$ to $W$ would not linearly extend to all of $V$. And conversely, if $\mathcal{B}$ didn't span then we would have distinct linear functions that agreed on $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "arbitrary (set) functions from $\mathcal{B}$ to $W$."

Comment: @Godbless Functions of sets, as opposed to linear (or otherwise "structure-preserving") functions. The point is that every function from $\mathcal{B}$ to $W$ corresponds to exactly one linear map $V\rightarrow W$, and this crucially uses *both* aspects of "basis-ness."

Comment: But why would the domain be $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: @Godbless Because that's the whole point of the theorem - that every linear map $V\rightarrow W$ is completely determined by its values on $\mathcal{B}$, and there are no restrictions on how such a map can behave on $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Think about an example. Take $V=W=\mathbb{R}^2$ (as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual way) and $\mathcal{B}=\{[0,1],[1,0]\}$ is the standard basis. Suppose I have any function whatsoever $$f: \mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2.$$ Do you see why the "basis-ness" of $\{[0,1],[1,0]\}$ means that there is exactly one linear map $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ extending $f$? If I replace $\{[0,1],[1,0]\}$ with something bigger, some $f$s don't have corresponding $F$s, and if I replace $\{[0,1],[1,0]\}$ with something smaller then each $f$ has "too many" corresponding $F$s.

Comment: Well, we can define linear maps without reference to bases... So, do you take $F$ to be a representation of a linear function by a matrix?
That would make sense, because we can only construct such matrices if we have defined ordered bases on the domain and codomain?

Comment: @Godbless Yes, exactly! It is the exact properties that we require of a basis, neither more nor less, that makes the correspondence between matrices and linear maps work as well as it does. In particular that every matrix yields a linear map, and the same linear map can't have two different matrix representations (without changing basis).

Answer (score 1):

It’s not that the basis itself is so important. What is really important is the idea of a free vector space. Fix a field $k$. When we say “vector space”, we mean $k$-vector space.

Given a set $S$, a free vector space over $S$ consists of a vector space $V$, together with a function $\eta : S \to V$, such that for all vector spaces $U$ and all functions $f : S \to U$, there exists a unique linear map $g : V \to U$ such that $g \circ \eta = f$.

Note that we typically refer to *the* free vector space on $S$, although according to my definition, there can be more than one. This is because, up to unique isomorphism, there is only one free vector space on each set. Given free vector spaces $(V, \eta)$ and $(V’, \eta’)$ on $S$, there is a unique isomorphism $w : V \to V’$ such that $w \circ \eta = \eta’$. This justifies using the word *the*.

The notion of a “free vector space” is the notion which is of extremely general importance. The idea of a free structure over a set can be seen in all areas of mathematics. In ring theory, we study polynomials, which are free algebras. In group theory, we study free groups. In topology, we can equip a set with the discrete topology, which is the free topological space on the set. In all areas of math and computer science, given a set $\Sigma$, we talk about the monoid $\Sigma^*$ of finite lists of elements of $\Sigma$, which is the free monoid on $\Sigma$ - computer scientists call this the set of strings on the alphabet $\Sigma$.

All of these constructions comply with a generalised notion of “free” - there is some structure $V$, and some inclusion map $\eta : S \to V$, such that for all functions maps $f : S \to U$, there is a unique structure-preserving map $g : V \to U$ such that $g \circ \eta = f$. It turns out that whenever there are arbitrarily large structures of the kind we’re considering, the $\eta$ map will always be injective. So we can think of $\eta : S \to V$ as including $S$ as a subset of $V$.

What does this have to do with basises (bases)? It turns out that given a vector space $V$ and a subset $B \subseteq V$, we have the following fact:

> Theorem: $B$ is a basis of $V$ if and only if $V$ is the free vector space on $B$, with the inclusion map $B \subseteq V$ being $\eta$.

This immediately clues us in to the importance of basis. Free things have all kinds of convenient properties. But in fact, there is another reason why bases are so important. And that is

> Thm. Assuming the axiom of choice, every vector space has a basis.

This means that all vector spaces are free, which is a remarkable result. We know that not all groups, monoids, topological spaces, etc. are free. There must be something truly special about vector spaces in particular.

Finally, when dealing with finite-dimensional vector spaces - that is, free vector spaces on a finite sets - we have a number of nice theorems. First, we can immediately identify a free vector space on $n$ elements with $k^n$, a vector space with a very simple and convenient structure. We know exactly what linear maps $k^n \to k^m$ look like - we represent them using matrices. So this allows us to classify maps between any two finite-dimensional vector spaces using matrices, as long as we’ve fixed a basis list for the domain and codomain.